# Cakephp 4 password hashing

Tags: php, cakephp, password-hash

I am new to cakephp, trying to hash password as in the cookbook. In my db the password field is user_password, so I wrote the following code:

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'user_email' => true,
        'user_password' => true,
        'user_created' => true,
        'user_modified' => true,
        'user_right' => true,
    ];

    protected $_hidden=[
      'user_password',  
    ];

    protected function _setPassword(string $user_password) : ?string
    {
        if (strlen($user_password) > 0) {
            return (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($user_password);
        }
    }
```

It not working, just saving the text to the db.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: protected function _setUserPassword(...